# Trouble with maven in Netbeans

Tags: maven, netbeans

I want to create maven project in Netbeans. So, I do File->New project->Maven->Java Application. After that I try to build the project and get error:
The POM for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:jar:2.10 is missing, no dependency information available.
But I can build this project from command line with mvn compile. Could uou tell me what is the problem with Netbeans?

Answer (score 0):

NetBeans is using 3.0.4 maven by default. Unless you change that in Tools/Options menu. Are you building with 3.0.4 as well or are you using some earlier versions (2.x)?
That would explain the behaviour because 3.0.4 will not blindly rely on what artifact is in local repository but some additional metadata is also consulted to make sure your project build with the given set of defined repositories.

A common example when the problem occurs to me.
I use central directly everything downloads. when I later add a mirror, all artifacts are checked again through the mirror to make sure they are accessible. if teh Mirror doesn't actually mirror central, I get an error that way.

Another common example is: when building with 2.x, the additional metadata is not written, when later building with 3.0.4, all remote context is checked no matter what is present in local repo and the additional metadata files are constructed.